# install4j v6 ant tasks compatibility issue?

Tags: install4j

We have recently upgraded to install4j v6 and discovered that tasks located in $INSTALL4J_HOME/bin/ant.jar are not compatible with JDK 1.6 and require JDK 1.7 at least.

Am I correct or we do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. The install4j IDE and the command line compiler require Java 7 or higher for install4j 6.x.